# WebClient.DownloadString throwing nullreference exception

Tags: c#, webclient, nullreferenceexception, unity-webgl

I am trying to download the content of a XML file stored at a specific web address. bellow is the code

```
 WebClient wc = new WebClient();
 string data=wc.DownloadString(ghxuri);
 XElement xml = XElement.Parse(data);
```

ghxuri is the link to download the file which has the following format `http://path/xml_file`.
I am able to download the file by clicking the link and can also run it from my c# project. But when I am trying to execute the same function using a webgl build its throwing the following error

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

> Rethrow as WebException: An exception occurred during a WebClient request.
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal (System.Uri address, System.Net.WebRequest& request) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0

> (Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

I am not able to understand the nullreferenceexception reason.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: The problem was due to the fact that webgl build doest not support any function from system.net. I have to use js for this.

Answer (score 1):

This could be probably your WebGl doesn’t have access to internet. This is expected due to a security implications, the .Net networking will not work in WebGl. See the below link for more details and alternative.
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/webgl-networking.html